# How to make Firebase CRUD operations?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to swift and Firebase anyone help me please  to understand with swift code making request for    GET  , POST , PUT , DELETE request Firebase .

thank you

Comment: Read the firebase documentation.

Comment: Are you asking how to read and write data from Firebase using Swift or do you want to use another language? Firebase doesn't have a GET or POST in the Swift API so that's why I'm asking. You can add one with a third party library but it's unclear what you are asking. And @Dravidian comment is super on point too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for HTTP Requests

**Swift Code**

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get") // method defaults to `.get`

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/put", method: .put)
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/delete", method: .delete)
```

See [Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for Detail

Comment: iOS have api URLSession for network request. why i choose Alamofire 3rd party   ? could you explain ? please